# Brain Connectogram or Connectivity Visualization

Tags: visualization, windows

Can anybody please guide me how can I draw the following figure in my windows 10 environment, I mean is there some built-in online tool or software that I can use for this purpose?

In my case I have two average correlation matrices , one for healthy subjects and one for ADHD subjects and each matrix is 90 x 90 as I am using AAL brain tempalte.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might find this link useful if you are R user.
https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/chord-diagram.html

Comment: Let me see this link , thanks for your help really！